# Tabs in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I need to put two tabs on my aspx page (c#). Is there already done tabs control  for aspx ?

Answer (score 5):

Ajax has tabs you can use:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/tabs/tabs.aspx

jQuery also has tabs you could use, which in my opinion is the better choice:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

In strictly ASP.NET you can use multiview, and make tabs, here is a tutorial for that:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/TabControl.aspx

Comment: i would recoomend jqueryui tabs

Comment: 3rd link 404s now :(

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap is commonly used with aspx so I used it on my webpage for tabs.
[This](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp) is a tutorial page.

Please find below an example for two tabs:

```
<div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <li class="active"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings tab</a></li>
   <li><a href="#info" aria-controls="info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Information tab</a></li>
 </ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="settings">
   </div>
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="info">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You need to have bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js references in page head section.

Comment: It's best to not just link to an answer (what if the link stops working?) but to also give a summary & explanation of the answer.

Comment: This does the job elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send down all the tabs' contents and just have a locally (and instantly) swapped experience, I recommend https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp. You put your content in divs, and use just a tiny bit of JavaScript to swap out which one is visible. No extra/3rd-party component or framework, just simple HTML/JS that just works.

Super simplistic subset from the above: Content in divs like `<div id="tab1">content</div>`, then show one with `document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "block";` and hide the others with `none` instead of `block`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard ASP.NET component, but you can use Microsoft's ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit library.
Here is the [component](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/tabs/tabs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple menus using CSS. This site shows you step by step how to create one, which you can then customise as required.

http://www.secondpicture.com/tutorials/web_design/css_ul_li_horizontal_css_menu.html